# AngularJS call an href on space bar press (ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hyperlink, angular-ui-router

How to do? space bar = 32 Maybe space bar trap is tricky in Angular? Some permutations:

```
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? '/settings' : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? '#/settings' : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? $eval('/settings') : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? $eval('#/settings') : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? $eval(/settings) : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? go('/settings') : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? go('#/settings') : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? go(#/settings) : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? $location.path('/settings') : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? $location.path('#/settings') : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? javascript:angular.element(document.getElementById('MainController'))).scope().go('#/settings') : null" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? javascript:angular.element(document.getElementById('MainController'))).scope().go('#/settings') : null"
```

In my AngularJS/Bootstrap/FontAwesone app ui-router is main menu handler so I have links like:

```
<li role="presentation">
  <a id="settings-tab" ui-sref="settings" tabindex="2" role="tab"
    ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? go('/settings') : null" 
  <span class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></span>Settings</a>
</li>
```

With ui-router an ui-sref="settings" gets translated into href="/settings" ui-sref="setting"

Comment: For starters, use '' inside "" as in `"$event.keyCode == 32 ? '/settings' : null"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out original quotes insanity. I have updated entire question permutations with sane quotes. No joy yet.

Comment: You'd be better off calling a function like `ng-keyup="spaceBarHandler()"` and in your controller, handle the function through there.

Comment: Below is the long answer, but this shorty works `data-ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? $state.go('userLogin') : null"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like the answer, which is really geared toward UI-Router is to:

1) inside AngularJS .run place ui-router $state on $rootScope
 2) create function in AngularJS .controller that calls UI-Router $state.go(locationToGo)
 3) add some $stateNotFound error handling for debugging

```
angular
  .module('MainApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.utils',
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'use strict';

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
      })
      .state('settings', {
        url: "/settings",
        templateUrl: 'settings/settings.html'
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/error?code=404");
  })
  .run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $log) {
    'use strict';

    $state.transitionTo('home');
    // You need to put $state on $rootScope to access it in controller
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', 
      function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams) {
        $log.log(unfoundState.to); // "unknown.state"
        $log.log(unfoundState.toParams); // {a:1, b:2}
        $log.log(unfoundState.options); // {inherit:false} + default options
      $state.go("error?code=404");
    });
  })
  .controller('MainController', function ($scope, $state, $log) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.goToOnSpace = function (event, locationToGo) {
      if (event.keyCode === 32) {
        $log.log(locationToGo);
        $state.go(locationToGo);
      }
    };
});
```

The HTML code looks like:

```
<li role="presentation">
  <a id="settings-item" ui-sref="settings" tabindex="-1" 
     data-ng-keypress="goToOnSpace($event, 'settings')" 
     role="menuitem">&nbsp;&nbsp;Settings</a>
</li>
```

Comment: And the short answer is `data-ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 32 ? $state.go('userLogin') : null"`

Answer (score 1):

Create a function and pass a parameter that defines the location where you want to go.

```
<a ui-sref="settings" ng-keypress="goToOnSpace($event, 'settings')">My link</a>
```

and in the controller check the key pressed and where you want to go:

```
$scope.goToOnSpace = function (e, locationToGo) {
    if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.charCode === 32) {
        // Code that checks additional Parameter to go to requested link
        if(locationToGo === "home"){
            window.location.href = '/#/';
        } else {
            window.location.href = '/#/' + locationToGo;
        }
    }
};
```

You can still include ui-router to handle when you click the link with the cursor, but an additional function could be the way to go to take care of the space key press.

Comment: Tried this and no joy. In my little app, the "window.location.href = '/' + locationToGo;" is actually enough (no if needed) because the root of the menu is "/home" not "/". But the $location.path('/settings') I tried and the window.location.href you mentioned is not getting the job done. Thanks though!

Comment: @Brad Sturtevant could you make a jsfiddle so we can try to di something from there?

Comment: No problem! There are javascript libraries which are a part of my app that do not have CDN (and significant, Bootstrap Accessibility Plugin, v1.0.3 by the PayPal Accessibility Team) but could focus without problem. Take me a day...

Comment: GitHub: git clone https://github.com/bradsturtevant/swks-gencg-seed.git  This code needs Yeoman, Bower, Grunt, Less. Can follow build instructions at https://github.com/cgross/generator-cg-angular/tree/master I noticed that IF I included the Paypal Accessibility Plugin the main tabs in navbar did work with code a lot like you mentioned. UI-Router did need window.location.href = '/#/' + locationToGo. But would not work in dropdown menu. Maybe this is because drop has a different scope than main navbar? The Paypal Accessibility Plugin is not available in Plunker because no CDN :(

Comment: I did not clone the git yet. But I checked the drop down in the plunker, and it works with the spacebar as expected, at least for the Settings and the Themes link (not the display density). If I understood you correctly, those 2 links (seetings and themes), dont work when the Paypal plugin is present?

Comment: I tested by mouse click on Home, then press tab key once (to highlight Login) then press Enter. You will see in main window Login Main Login Aside. If you then mouse click on Home will see Home Main Home Aside. Now to see spacebar fail, mouse click on Home then press tab once to again highlight Login, and press spacebar key--you should see Login Main Login Aside, but you don't. The main view did not change.

Comment: By saying I couldn't do anything with settings/themes I mean: Try mouse clicking on Home then pressing tab key three times, then press Enter key to open dropdown, then hightlight (dont actually mouse click, just point at) either Settings or Themes and press either Enter or Spacebar and nothing really happens--Niether Settings Main Settings Aside or Themes Main Themes Aside will apear. Only way they show up is with mouse click. The Accesability Plugin (in GitHub project) makes it possible to navigate most of app with ketboard only, and Login will start working, but settings/themes will not.

Comment: To build the GitHub project you need to install nodejs (and its npm), npm install -g bower, npm install -g grunt-cli. And after Git clone do cd swks-gencg-seed; npm install; bower install; then grunt serve; then point a browser at http://localhost:9001

Comment: The code for spacebar trap does not work in Firefox, but does in IE (shocking) and Chrome. What a mess!

Comment: I have updated the answer for the spacebar work in firefox, I'll check the rest when I get a chance

Comment: Cool! I noticed in the AngularJS docs that $location service changed between 1.2x and 1.3x. Read: http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/docs/guide/$location  In 1.3x are supposed to use: $window.location.href = value (your code search val) while in 1.2x supposed to use two calls: $location.href = value; $location.update(value); Good to know! Caveat is that UI-Router, not $router is involved! You are thinking latest, while I should be too, but..

Comment: I will check firefox mods. Unbeivable! Angular insulation? What! Sound good though!

Comment: Cool! I noticed in the AngularJS docs that $location service changed between 1.2x and 1.3x. Read: http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/docs/guide/$location  In 1.3x are supposed to use: $window.location.href = value (your code search val) while in 1.2x supposed to use two calls: $location.href = value; $location.update(value); Good to know! Espec cause I am using 1.2x So Sorry on that one. Must now try your Firefox code bro. Still, what a mess!